# How to capture photo automatically in android phone? 0

Tags: android

I want created my own camera application. And when I click the button it takes the picture and saves it in the galary. What I want to do is to take the picture without a preview and without clicking any button.

I am searching many but I did not get proper solution one code I founded.But when I run this it is Error.Please give me Exact Solution. You can give me your own project for automatically capture photo and save gallery automatic.

[enter link MainActivity.java here](http://codepad.org/kR2Red2H)

Error:

```
  07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.capturephotoautometic_one/com.example.capturephotoautometic_one.SimpleCameraIntentFragment}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:340)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:317)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at com.example.capturephotoautometic_one.SimpleCameraIntentFragment.onResume(SimpleCameraIntentFragment.java:46)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5182)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
07-11 09:51:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: first define value for cam object

Comment: what's value bro?? @Prag's

Comment: cam object is null...so you have to define value for it... try `cam = getCameraInstance();`

Comment: It's error..bro...@Prag's

Comment: bro it's now not crashed but did not capture photo?

Comment: I update code and Error